# Running WCF Windows Service as InstanceContextMode.PerCall

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, windows-services

I have a WCF Service which is configured to run as a windows service but it only works if I set the `InstanceContextMode` to `Single`.When I change it to be `PerCall` and re-install the service it becomes inaccessible.

Could somebody please clarify if I run a WCF service as a windows service does the context *HAVE* to be set to Single and why is that?

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class CateringSSTService : ICateringSSTService
```

**UPDATE:Here's the hosting code**

```
    private ICateringSSTService _cateringSSTService;
    private ServiceHost _serviceHost;
    private Task _executionTask;

    public CateringSSTServer()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _executionTask = new Task(ManagerStartup);
        _executionTask.Start();
    }

    private void ManagerStartup()
    {
        try
        {
            _cateringSSTService = new CateringSSTService();
            _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_cateringSSTService);
            _serviceHost.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_serviceHost != null && _serviceHost.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                _serviceHost.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you run a WCF service as a windows service? Self-Hosting? If so, where is the code?

Comment: It's hosted on a Windows 2003 server @nvoigt

Comment: That's not what I meant. You cannot just take those two lines and "host it as windows service". Where is your hosting code?

Comment: I've added the hosting code @nvoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a single object and passing it to the singleton constructor of `ServiceHost`. How is this ServiceHost supposed to create a new object every call? That cannot work.

If you want PerCall (or PerSession or anything but Singleton) you need to pass the *type* of your class to the `ServiceHost` constructor so it can create new instances of this type at runtime.

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CateringSSTService));
```

If you hadn't silently swallowed the exception, the Runtime would have told you what the problem is. Apply some proper error handling for future problems.